# Generating RSS for Google Reader and other RSS Readers from Joomla 1.5 Article Categories

Tags: joomla, rss, blogs

I am creating a site that has a blog section. I want people to be able to have a button on my site that people can click on to subscribe to the blog articles. Please how can I achieve this? Which extension do I have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this page:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/rss-syndicate